# How to make a binary counter

Tags: schematics, binary

How do you make it so that a light goes on after a button has been pressed twice then off when pressed twice more?

I'm pretty stumped on this one and searches don't yield results. Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment, so we won't just hand you the answer. Tell us how much you **do** understand about the problem and describe exactly where you get stuck.

Comment: urm I don't study at all, the point where I'm stuck is preventing it from self oscillating (constantly switching from on and off while the button is down). I gave the simplest question which will give a means to a solutions for my hobbyist application - I want to octave down a square wave input. I mean I could just use an arduino but I would rather know how to achieve it using raw components. nb I am quite new to electronics and come from a cs background.

Comment: Dividing a square wave frequency is an entirely different problem than dealing with a pushbutton. You should have been clear about what you really wanted from the start.

Comment: I described the problem so I could use the solution in a certain way, because of how else I will be using it. I have come to something I think will work, it contains a lot of transistors, and 2 capacitors. I achieved it using AND and NOT logic and cancelling out double negatives. I just need to get a few resistors then I can test it.

Comment: the eclles jordan flip-flip can be modified to switch state when a pulse is received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To divide a square wave **frequency** in half, the classic approach is to use a D flip-flop, such as a CMOS CD4013. Connect the input square wave to the clock input of the flip-flop, and connect the \$\overline{Q}\$ output back to the \$D\$ input. The output signal should be taken from the \$Q\$ output of the flip-flop.

Comment: Actually, the classic way is to use a JK flip-flop with the J and K inputs tied high. D-type flip-flops are for wussies. And people like me, who prefer them.

Comment: thanks for your answer, maybe I should have specified that I do not wish to use external chips. for the thing I'm making it only need to go to transistors so it doesn't need to retain anything from the original wave apart from the frequency (relative to a half).

Comment: @equave Yes, if didn't want to use "external chips" you should have said that clearly in your question. If you still want help you need to add a complete description of your situation to the text of the question.

Comment: I am now using ICs, thanks.